# Site Header Compatability in IE6, using Floats and Absolute Positioning

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

After designing and coding a standards-compliant website, that works functionally in normal browsers (Firefox, Chrome, etc), I now need to make it look identical (or mostly so) in Internet Explorer, down to Internet Explorer 6.

The current version of the website can be found at http://www.adwas.org/test/redesign/, with a minimal version of the problem at http://jsfiddle.net/FdS6L/

The problem I'm having is that at and below the area with the logo, it absolutely breaks down in IE6 (and 7, I'm guessing, still). I've already attempted to fix some of the issues, using the star-hack selector, though it still looks heavily borked. My question is: how do I maintain the size of the header, and get the elements to be (somewhat, if not totally) visible, similar to how it looks in most browsers?

#### Note:

I'm not adverse to adding JavaScript for the layout to work as necessary in IE6. (applies mostly to the submenu navigation)

Comment: I would *like* to help you out here, but your page will take too long to debug. IE6 is very annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying to work on your site, and got it to this point: http://jsfiddle.net/3m367/3/. I basically cleaned up some code and restructured the header, where the bars are full-width automatically rather than forcefully (`overflow-x` is a CSS3 property, so wouldn't work for older browsers). This displays fine in IE7 and up. However, I stumbled upon an issue with your navigation - IE6 supports `:hover` pseudo-class on `a` elements only, so selectors like `li:hover` wouldn't work. Yet, you cannot put your submenus inside parent menu item's `a` element because you cannot have links within links. I'm not sure if it's possible to do that drop-down menu in IE6 without using JavaScript. Other than that, the navigation seems to be the only thing messing up in IE6 right now.

Comment: you're right about the li:hover support, "suckerfish" is a good example of doing the menu in the existing structure, but with javascript for IE6. Using a conditionally included JS file for IE6 would be a good idea if this functionality is needed.

Comment: That's looking notably better, thanks. Updated the question slightly - I definitely _would not_ mind using Javascript to fix the submenu functionality - I'm already using the Prototype library on the page for some other Javascript for the site.

Comment: @Nightfirecat: To make `li:hover` work in IE6, here are some options for you: [Whatever:hover](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html), [the Suckerfish JavaScript](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/), or write your own JavaScript using Prototype to make it shorter.

Comment: According to [IE NetRenderer](http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/) and [your modified HTML/CSS, in JSBin](http://jsbin.com/orakuq), the submenu navigation seems borked, even without the `:hover` support (or is that still the fault?)

Comment: @Nightfirecat Alrighty, I went in and made a few more changes to the CSS, and here is the updated document: http://jsbin.com/orakuq/3. I fixed the double-margin bug in `#center-nav` which I didn't notice last time, and disabled drop-down menus for IE6 (that's what `_display: none` does - it only affects IE6). Also, for some reason IE6 was rendering the `#sitenav` menu items with full width - I inserted `_width: 30px` there to ensure that it renders them with 30 pixels width (due to its box model bug it expands the box to fit the contents, which is what we need).

Comment: @Nightfirecat I also fixed the submenu item width on IE7 (they weren't occupying full `ul` width for some reason. As for the dropdown menu on IE6, I suggest going ahead with Suckerfish, per Danjah's comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `float: left` on `#sitenav li` you could try:

```
#sitenav {
    display: table;
}

#sitenav ul {
    display: table-row;
}

#sitenav li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

You should also consider using [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to hide a set of IE-only stylesheets from other browsers, especially a stylesheet targeting something as old and archane as IE6. If you don't get anything to work with bare CSS and conditional comments, you should consider trying [HTML5 Shiv](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/) and do the markup with HTML5 (which I believe you should either way).

Comment: Table-related `display` values are not supported properly by IE6 and IE7. Besides, a table display wouldn't really do much there since it's the submenus that mess up the layout.